# How can I get the coordinates of a rectangular DOM element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom, graph-drawing

I am trying to draw a graph using D3 where the nodes are rectangular. Then, for some reason, I need to find out the coordinates of those drawn nodes to draw the edges between the nodes. How can I get the coordinates of these rectangular nodes? I have tried doing this:

```
var ID = d3.select("#node_1")
                 .getBoundingClientRect()
                 .data(graph.nodes);
```

Here, I am using **d3.select("#node_1")** for selecting the particular node with ID **node_1**. But this **getBoundingClientRect()** does not seem to work in this case. What should I do?

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect()` is a function the brower provides, not a D3 one. You need to use `document.querySelector("#node_1").getBoundingClientRect()` and use the object it returns.

Comment: I just tried that. It says ```document.querySelector(...).getBoundingClientRect(...).data``` is not a function.

Comment: Why are you chaining `.data()`? The coordinates are returned by `.getBoundingClientRect()` - the returned object doesn't have a `.data` method (hence the error). The use of .data is confusing given your goal: are you trying to set the data associated with the selection while also getting the coordinates? As a side note: you can use `selection.node().getBoundingClientRect()` if you have a D3 selection and don't want to reselect using `document.querySelector()...`

Comment: That solved my problem. Thanks a lot @AndrewReid

Comment: I am facing another issue here. I am getting exactly the same coordinates for other nodes in my graph here when I am using ```selection.node().getBoundingClientRect()``` here.